# The 3pl api central when creating of order its not working

Tags: c#

Im working with 3pl api central for creating order which is base on this link http://api.3plcentral.com/rels/orders/orders but its not working, im using C#.Net framework 4.6.1 and additional headache it doesn't return a specific error message, any lacking or issue on the class structure. Thank you.

Looking for your kind help.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What exact response you are getting from the API? How do you confirm that it is not working? You need to share the relevant code explain the issue with little more details.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As Chetan said, please ask a specific and detailed question including the corresponding piece of code (maybe simplified) and the exact error message or problem.

Comment: Sorry for very late reply. it was already fixed, but another error encountered.

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "goo6". The conflict occurred in database "tpl512", table "dbo.UserLogin", column 'UserLoginID'.
The statement has been terminated.
at Orm.XactionBase`2.FinishAndCommit() in c:\jenkins\workspace\wms-release_1.322\WMS\Orm\XactionBase.cs:line 68
at WMS.V2.Order.Controllers.OrdersController.Post(OrderCreate order) in c:\jenkins\workspace\wms-release_1.322\WMS\V2\WebApis\Orders\Controllers\OrdersController.cs:line 480


Hoping for your help :)